# How to access json array elements in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I'am having problem in accessing json array elements. Below is the response when i send data using POST method in ajax. How can i access only middlename, result from response. Please help me

```
{
"class": "MyF",
 "result": {
 "authToken": "abcd",
 "authTokens": [
 {
   "name": "ABC",
    "class": "AuthToken"
 }
],
"class": "User",
"middlename": "xyz",
"lastname": "abc",
},
"result": "1234"
}
```

Comment: That's a correct **json** array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

In you case

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{
"class": "MyF",
 "result": {
 "authToken": "abcd",
 "authTokens": [
 {
   "name": "ABC",
    "class": "AuthToken"
 }
],
"class": "User",
"middlename": "xyz",
"lastname": "abc",
},
"result": "1234"
}');
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using jQuery you could just do

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('jsonstring');
```

Then you could get middlename by

```
obj.middlename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    var parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
});
```

This create object JSON, and you can traversing on him.